# multiprocessing.Pool().apply_async() doesn't seem to run my function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run 2 functions over two differents process with the help of multiprocessing.Pool().apply_async() , but it doesn't seem to run my function. No error messages tho.
But when I try my function without multiprocessing then it works perfectly.
Here is how my code looks like(short version) :

```
import multiprocessing, twitch_integration
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
p.apply_async(twitch_integration.get_user_followers, args=(userid1, "", conn,))
p.apply_async(twitch_integration.get_user_followers, args=(userid2, "", conn,))
p.close()
p.join()
```

I don't know if it's important to note, but get_user_followers function is recursive and requests module.
I've put a print at the very beginning of get_user_followers, but it doesn't print anything.

I've been searching for the last 4 hours, I'm not exaggerating. If anyone could help me I would be very thankful.
Thank you.

After asking for the results as @Steve mentioned, it raised a new error and here is the traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 89, in <module>
    main(conn, cursor);
  File "main.py", line 68, in main
    r = result.get(timeout=1)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 272, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object")
TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object
```

Here is the get_user_followers function for more details(I know it's ugly but I'm getting started with Python and programmation):

```
import requests, json, sys, time
from mysql.connector import Error
def get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn):
    global FOLLOWER_COUNT
    global ERROR_COUNT
    global OAUTH_TOKEN
    global TOTAL_FOLLOWER
    global ERROR_IN_A_ROW
    print("YES")
    after = "&after={0}".format(pagination)
    first = "&first=100"
    query = 'users/follows?to_id={0}{1}{2}'.format(user_id, first, pagination if pagination == "" else after)
    try:
        response = get_response(query)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("pause 1 seconde. . . Retrying same request")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Request error: ", e)
        get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn)
        return
    finally:
        pass
    if response.status_code == 200:
        ERROR_IN_A_ROW = 0
    elif response.status_code == 401:
        print(response.json())
        print("HTTP Error 401")
        ERROR_IN_A_ROW += 1
        if ERROR_IN_A_ROW == 3:
            print("AFTER 3 HTTP ERROR IN A ROW - EXITING PROGRAM")
            print("pagination: ", pagination, " user_id", user_id)
            return
        OAUTH_TOKEN = requests.post(POST_URL, data=POST_PARAMS).json()['access_token']
        get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn)
        return
    elif response.status_code == 429:
        print(response.json())
        print("HTTP Error 429")
        time.sleep(int(response.json()['Ratelimti-Reset']))
        get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn)
        return
    else:
        print(response.json())
        print("HTTP Error {0}".format(response.status_code))
        ERROR_IN_A_ROW += 1
        if ERROR_IN_A_ROW == 3:
            print("AFTER 3 HTTP ERROR IN A ROW - EXITING PROGRAM")
            print("pagination: ", pagination, " user_id", user_id)
            return
        get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn)
        return
    response = response.json()
    TOTAL_FOLLOWER = response['total']
    length = len(response['data'])
    if length == 0:
        try:
            print("{0}/{1}".format(FOLLOWER_COUNT, TOTAL_FOLLOWER) + " ({0}%)".format(format((FOLLOWER_COUNT * 100 / TOTAL_FOLLOWER), ".2f")) + "\r", end="")
        except:
            print("{0}/{1}".format(FOLLOWER_COUNT, TOTAL_FOLLOWER))
        FOLLOWER_COUNT = 0
        ERROR_COUNT = 0
        TOTAL_FOLLOWER = 0
        return 1
    pagination = response['pagination']['cursor']
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        try:
            conn.cursor().execute("""INSERT INTO user (id, username) VALUES ({0}, '{1}')""".format(response['data'][i]['from_id'], str(response['data'][i]['from_name'])))
        except Error as e:
            print("An error has occured : ", e)
            ERROR_COUNT += 1
        finally:
            pass
        i += 1
        FOLLOWER_COUNT += 1
        try:
            print("{0}/{1}".format(FOLLOWER_COUNT, TOTAL_FOLLOWER) + " ({0}%)".format(format((FOLLOWER_COUNT * 100 / TOTAL_FOLLOWER), ".2f")) + " {0}".format(user_id))
        except:
            print("{0}/{1}".format(FOLLOWER_COUNT, TOTAL_FOLLOWER))
    get_user_followers(user_id, pagination, conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your jobs/functions to run, you have to ask for their results.  This should run your jobs:

```
import multiprocessing, twitch_integration
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
result = p.apply_async(twitch_integration.get_user_followers, args=(userid1, "", conn,))
r = result.get(timeout=1)
result = p.apply_async(twitch_integration.get_user_followers, args=(userid2, "", conn,))
r = result.get(timeout=1)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: I'm having a new error : TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object
I'm looking right now how to solve it so I can see if your solution worked :)

Comment: It actually shouldn't matter to the outcome whether you `.get()` the result. But doing `.get()` should always be done anyway, because - as you just discovered - that's sometimes the **only** way to see exceptions raised asynchronously   If possible, try to rewrite the code so that you call a named module-level function instead. Trying to call a method of a complex object creates worlds of possible failure modes, hard to track down because they occur not in the main program, but in the bowels of the mp machinery.

Comment: Do you know what pickling is?  Your program is trying to turn an object into a static representation that can be sent from one process to another.  Which object that is, I can't know because you haven't given enough information.  The problem is that this object it's trying to serialize contains a socket and therefore can't be serialized.  This makes sense.  A live socket connection can't be fully represented as some bytes, as the socket's state involves the state of the systems on both sides of the socket.

Comment: @TimPeters, I'm trying to understand what you're saying.  If there are `print` statements in my job functions, and what those print statements print to the console doesn't show up unless I call `.get()`, doesn't that mean that they haven't run?  Or is the multiprocessing module really capturing all `stdout` output and then dumping it to the console only when I ask for the result? That sounds a bit far fetched to me. I assumed that the lack of any output to my console meant.that my code hadn't run.  Please explain what's going on if you believe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Steve I just learned what it is. a static representation is basically addresses in C if I understand right. I cannot paste here the whole traceback but here is the interesting line I think :   File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 272, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object") as you said, it seems to be about the socket. I imported requests and used it to send http request(request.get; request.post) which seem to be an issue now with multiprocessing..

Comment: Why can't you paste the whole traceback?  Put it in your question!  That's where it belongs.  It's not just something you CAN do, it's something you SHOULD do.

Comment: Your print never executed because your method was never invoked, and your method was never invoked because the asynchronous mp machinery _trying_ to run the method failed early in the process - with a pickling error, while trying - but failing - to create a serialization of the `twitch_integration` object to send to a worker process. It's that **error** you don't see unless you `get()`. The exception occurs asynchronously (has nothing to do with what the main program is doing), so is suppressed - there's no good way to report it. Unless you `get()`. Then there's a synchronization point.

Comment: @Steve I posted it. In the future I'll add whatever details I have that may help others helping me, my bad on this one.

Comment: @TimPeters - you're missing what I'm saying.  I'm not the OP.  I thought I knew how to help the OP, but I went off and put my own example together to be sure.  My job function contained ONY a print statement.  My setup was otherwise like the OPs.  When I ran the test, I got no output on my console.  Only when I called `.get()` did I get output on my console.  I assumed that meant that only when I called `.get()` did my function run.  How can it be otherwise? - I. assume that the OP wasn't getting the pickling error prior to calling `.get` for the same reason...his/her code hadn't been running.

Comment: @Steve, so did I - created a function containing only a `print()`. Worked fine. Continued to work fine when I added a `sleep()` too. The OP's `p.join()` blocks until the worker processes are finished, and they're not finished until the async calls complete. I can't guess what went wrong with _your_ code because - like the OP - you didn't actually post it ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I posted the other complete function from the twitch_integration

Comment: @MarsCreativityCiv, the `conn` argument is apparently a socket connection, and it should be abundantly clear by now that you can't share that across processes this way - it can't be pickled. Rewrite the code so that each worker creates its own connection?

Comment: @TimPeters Can I kiss you ? It works <3 I just moved the conn creator function in the same file as get_user_followers and now it works. Also, it doesn't need the result = & r = result.get(timeout=1) anymore,

Comment: @MarsCreativityCiv, just a virtual kiss, please - there's a pandemic ;-)  But, for reasons already explained, do the `.get()` anyway! Else future exceptions can vanish without a trace too.